# D3 ticks change position when changing focus

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph, nvd3.js

I am using an NVD3 multibar graph with a focus chart. I want the ticks on my secondary (top) x-axis to line up properly with the bars on the primary (bottom) x-axis - preferably at the beginning of them. Currently, the ticks don't line up with the bars at the same place. Some of them are over a neighbouring date or in the middle of the bar, as shown below:

[image]

The ticks coincide with events on specific dates. Both axes use the same scale. Its domain is assigned on a brush event based on the extent of the selection on the context graph by the following:

```
 x.domain([new Date(extent[0]), new Date(extent[1])]);
```

I also tried this:

```
 x.domain([new Date(extent[0]), d3.time.day.offset(new Date(extent[1]), 1)]);
```

which lines up nicely at the front of the bars for the beginning selection, but doesn't keep the ticks in place when focus range is changed. How can I keep the ticks in line with their bars?

EDIT: I specify the location of the ticks using tickValues(). x is a `d3.time.scale()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I was missing bar data for some dates so the number of dates on the scale didn't match up to the number of bars. I fixed this by inserting 0 values in the data for missing dates.